# How to tell Jquery to run only the last mouseenter event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have set of slides and I want to enlarge a photo when a mouse enter on to a slide image.

When I bring the mouse over images all of the images enlarge to the order which I brought the mouse. How I can **force jquery to only excete the last mouse enter event and cancel all history mouse enter events**?

This is my jquery code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#hoverslider ul li").bind("mouseenter",function(){
            $(this).animate({
                width:"500px"
            },"slow");
            $(this).addClass("active");
            $("#hoverslider ul li:not(.active)").animate({
                width:"141px"
            });
            })
       $("#hoverslider ul li").bind("mouseleave",function(){
            $(this).animate({
               width:"213px"
            },"slow");
           $(this).removeClass("active");
           $("#hoverslider ul li:not(.active)").animate({
               width:"213px"
           });
       });
});
```

Please help me to go through this. Thanks!!

Comment: can you share the page url

Comment: @RohitAgrawa Sorry l am doing it on xampp. Will a screenshot be helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could initially [stop](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) all the `animations` in the `mouse enter` and animate the image where the mouse is currently in, But keep in mind that you should not `stop` the animations (all the elements, not the individual) before starting it in the `mouseleave`, Because it will help the element to revert back to the older state.

### [WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/At8XR/3/)

Try this out,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#hoverslider ul li").bind("mouseenter",function(){

            $("#hoverslider ul li").stop();
            $(this).stop().animate({
                width:"500px"
            },"slow");
            $(this).addClass("active");

            $("#hoverslider ul li:not(.active)").stop().animate({
                width:"141px"
            });
            })
       $("#hoverslider ul li").bind("mouseleave",function(){
            $(this).stop().animate({
               width:"213px"
            },"slow");
           $(this).removeClass("active");
           $("#hoverslider ul li:not(.active)").stop().animate({
               width:"213px"
           });
       });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setTimeout()` to trigger enlarge animation. In `mouseenter` event handler use `clearTimeout()` to cancel previous animation if it hasn't already started.

This way quick mouse move won't trigger all images to enlarge.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not fully understanding your question, but it seems that you could use the `hover` method this way

```
$( "#hoverslider ul li" ).hover(
        function(){
            $(this).animate({
                width:"500px"
            },"slow");
            $(this).addClass("active");
            $("#hoverslider ul li:not(.active)").animate({
                width:"141px"
            });
    },

    function(){
        $(this).animate({
               width:"213px"
        },"slow");
        $(this).removeClass("active");
        $("#hoverslider ul li:not(.active)").animate({
               width:"213px"
        });
    }
```

);

See it online
http://jsfiddle.net/augusto1982/At8XR/

If this is not what you need, please, let me know and I'll fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use underscore helper method debounce

http://underscorejs.org/#debounce

This will create a wrapper of your callback, and only call it once every x seconds while you still call it. That means, that you can have many mouse enter and the method is only going to be called once, and only after x seconds that no mouse enter is registered the function is ready to be called again.

Answer (score -2):

You should use jQuery's [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method to add events, rather than the older `bind` method. You can then disable event handlers using the [`off`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) method.

Comment: this not really answered OP's question